# How to replace gclid to custom parameter

Tags: google-ads-api

How do I change google ads gclid to a customer parameter:
Example: https://example.com/search/coffee+maker&c=1122&g=3344

when user comes from country "A" will show the above url and for country "B" will charge the c and g number only.I mean for every country the c & g number will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom parameters using the [CustomParameter mapping](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v11/CustomParameter). This can be used in the URL like [this](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/ads/upgraded-urls/fields).

If you want to remove the gclid as well you can do this by [disabling autotagging](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1033981?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article), although I wouldn't recommend this as it would impact Google Analytics and conversion tracking. You can have the gclid and the custom parameters working in parallel